# Hdd for server, will it work?

Tags: raid, hard-drive

i have a server : IBM System x3250 M3

its have 2 HDD slots, but currently only have 1 HDD, that is : HDD 500 TB Hotplug, sata, with part number 9CA154-176

i want to add one more HDD, but i only found with part number 9FY156-176 or 39M4514, can i used it & will raid 1 work?

Comment: What does your IBM technical sales rep. say?

Comment: it is used server, so i dont have IBM technical sales rep. btw i understand hot swap with raid 1, is it simple swap with raid 1 too?

Answer (score 1):

Michaelmore,

If the new drive is SATA 3.0 7200RPM then it should work. However if your goal is to configure Raid 1 then please plan on backing up your data before doing so (especially if this is an Production environment). I'm not sure how picky the controller is but there is always that risk of compatibility with a drive that is not "officially" supported by IBM. Personally I always go straight through the vendor when ordering replacements (ie. Dell, HP ect).

Here is a link to the manual for the x3250 M3. See page 11 for hard drive options: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/technotes/tips0803.pdf

Hope that helps

Comment: No important data currently, i have time for the test. 
thank you for the link & the page direction. GBU